# Vue: Is there a way to detect changes on my database laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My question is simple I'm getting data through my API, so what is the best and suitable way can I make to vueJS so whenever something changes on my database it will updated automatically to the user without the need of refreshing the page

Example:

The user enter my website and see that the name of the first user is `Alex` at that time `Alex` changed his name to `Jone` and it got changed on the database how will I make vueJS automatically update the page for the first user that he is seeing the name of `Alex`

this is my code:

```
<template>
<div class="w-50">
    <table class="table ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user.UID">
                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.timer }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                users: [],
                user: {
                    UID: '',
                    isActive: ''
                }
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/Myusers')
                .then(res => {
                    this.name = res.data;
                    console.log(res.data);
                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

What is the best way to make VueJS observing or watching the database for anychange without stressing the server?

Comment: Look at broadcasting: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting
With it you can broadcast events from Laravel. When you have some changing on Laravel you just send events and then catch it with Echo on js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using WebSockets if you need real-time communication between your API and your front-end App by implementing [broadcasting events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting), but be careful:

If you choose an [Open Source Alternative](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#open-source-alternatives) such as [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) you will be serving a WS server that uses about 400Mb of RAM. This package implements statistics and a debug dashboard that overloads your server.
In addition, the implementation is not easy: you will face some issues with SSL when you deploy to production and many headaches while trying to connect your front-end App to your socket.

I assume that most of your database actions are critical and you don't want to face a missing communication between your API and your front-end App, therefore you will need to make use of queues to be sure that broadcasting was correctly done or, in case it wasn't, a retry was attempted.

Saying that, you have to be aware that you will need workers for processing queues which will consume some server RAM depending on how many workers you have.

As per my experience, a small DigitalOcean droplet (1CPU 1GB RAM) wasn't enough for my API, which was insane since there are no complex algorithms at all.

Finally, I decided to use [pusher-channels](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#pusher-channels) which has a [free plan](https://pusher.com/channels/pricing) that may be enough for your purposes too. Integration was so easy and I've decreased the server stressing significantly.

IMO, you can implement laravel-websockets but taking care about server specs, or just use the suggested laravel way with pusher.

Comment: Great one more final question since you have mentioned queues, lets say i had 100K visitors and all of them they sent a 100K request and it has been queued, here if i have only one worker or 10 workers it will be a hell of time to process the queue can i have 100K workers!?

Comment: Yes, you can set the number of workers by changing the `numprocs`  in supervisor config file `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#configuring-supervisor` or locally via multiple tabs in your terminal `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-multiple-queue-workers`. But remember, the more workers you have, more server RAM is used

Comment: Thanks man for your help